# How do I load a local JSON file into a uitableview in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I've been trying to look for how to do it, but still have not been successful. I want to put a JSON file into a tableview

```
{
  "person":[
       {
         "name": "John",
         "age": "17",
       },
       {
         "name": "Bob",
         "age": "23",             
       }

   ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the details from the json string as follows.

`let listDetails = json["Person"] as? Array<[String:String]>)!`

and you can have your table view delegates as follows.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return listDetails.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("yourCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let dict = listDetails[indexPath.row] as? [String:String]
    let name = dict["name"]
    let age = dict["age"]

    //now assign this name and age to the textViews you have in your tableView.

    return cell
}
```

Hope it helps.